# Problema con [Authorize] en asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

favor su colaboración con lo siguiente:
Tengo un controlador con un par de acciones:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult conAut()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult sinAut()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Como podrán apreciar la diferencia entre las dos acciones es que una tiene el [Authorize] y la otra no, en el web.config tengo lo siguiente:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Credenciales/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

El problema es que cuando inicio el proyecto y me voy directamente a conAut no me redirecciona a Login, accede al conAut con normalidad pese a que no inicie sesión, hasta donde tengo entendido si en el web.config tengo configurado  entonces todas las acciones que tengan el Authorize deberían re-direccionar al Login cuando no se tenga usuario autenticado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes estar autenticado por la coockie de algun login previo, trata de cerrar el explorador y limpiar el cache.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta esto en el web.config:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
```

Comment: adicione tu sugerencia y sigo en lo mismo.